# grab 50 characters before and after a particular text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get 50 characters before and after a particular text using jquery.
For example:

> He has Ashish Nehra, who will retire from all forms of the game
>   shortly, to take inspiration from and Pathan says, “he has been a
>   wonderful warrior. He has done very well to make a comeback at this
>   age and shows anyone can do it. I am not that old and I am working
>   hard and my fitness is very good now.” “I want to improve my fielding
>   but I am not thinking ahead of myself.”

I need to get 50 characters after and before the word "warrior".

Answer (score 3):

Get the index for the word you are looking for and take into account its length, then grab the next 50 and previous 50 characters and join them if necessary:

```
const input = "He has Ashish Nehra, who will retire from all forms of the game shortly, to take inspiration from and Pathan says, “he has been a wonderful warrior. He has done very well to make a comeback at this age and shows anyone can do it. I am not that old and I am working hard and my fitness is very good now.” “I want to improve my fielding but I am not thinking ahead of myself.”"

let index = input.indexOf("warrior"),
    offset = "warrior".length;

let charactersAfter = input.substr(index + offset, 50),
    charactersBefore = input.substr(0, index).slice(-50),
    joined= charactersAfter + charactersBefore;

console.log(charactersAfter);
console.log(charactersBefore);
console.log(joined);
```

If the word is repeated, expect unexpected results or clarify the requirements.

**Note:** Didn't use jQuery as it is not necessary at all.

---

**EDIT:**

Using regex to match the whole word:

```
const input = "He has Ashish Nehra, who will retire from all forms of the game shortly, to take inspiration from and Pathan says, “he has been a wonderful warrior. He has done very well to make a comeback at this age and shows anyone can do it. I am not that old and I am working hard and my fitness is very good now.” “I want to improve my fielding but I am not thinking ahead of myself.”"

let index = input.match(/\bwarrior\b/).index,
    offset = "warrior".length;

let charactersAfter = input.substr(index + offset, 50),
    charactersBefore = input.substr(0, index).slice(-50),
    joined= charactersAfter + charactersBefore;

console.log(charactersAfter);
console.log(charactersBefore);
console.log(joined);
```

Comment: HI , I found a problem here, If the text is like this,

"He has Ashish Nehra, who will retire from all forms of the game shortly, to take inspiration from and Pathan says, “he has been a wonderful warriors. He has done very well to make a comeback at this age and shows anyone can do it. I am not that old and I am working hard and my fitness is very good now.” “I want to improve my fielding but I am not thinking ahead of myself.”

I think, this will not work properly.

Comment: @Raru Could you be more specific as to what does not work?

Comment: Please look at the text. I had changed the word "warrior" in the text to "warriors". And I am trying to check the word "warrior".

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. The string "warrior" is present even if the "s" character is attached, the question does not state it as a requirement.

Comment: @GorkaHernandez I agree that jQuery is not necessary but it could certainly reduce the amount of code needed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a javascript solution. First split the big string into two by matching "warrior". After that use substring to retrieve before and after particular string.
Hope there is only one "warrior".

```js
    var str = "He has Ashish Nehra, who will retire from all forms of the game shortly, to take inspiration from and Pathan says, “he has been a wonderful warrior. He has done very well to make a comeback at this age and shows anyone can do it. I am not that old and I am working hard and my fitness is very good now.” “I want to improve my fielding but I am not thinking ahead of myself." ;

    array = str.split("warrior") ;
    console.log( array[0].substring(array[0].length - 50 ) ) ;
    console.log( array[1].substring(0,50) ) ;
```

Comment: +1, good answer, however avoid using `alert` in examples, use `console.log` instead. This shows text output all in one place and is generally less irritating than having to close multiple popups.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) to get part of the string.

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(0, 4);
echo res;
// Result: Hell
```

Comment: OP is asking for string before and after the word "warrior".

Comment: He just need the 50 characters before and after the word "warrior".
There may be conditions where more than 1 word occurs. I think @Tomasz your answer dosen't meet his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() and slice().

```
var str='He has Ashish Nehra, who will retire from all forms of the game shortly, to take inspiration from and Pathan says, “he has been a wonderful warrior. He has done very well to make a comeback at this age and shows anyone can do it. I am not that old and I am working hard and my fitness is very good now.” “I want to improve my fielding but I am not thinking ahead of myself.”';
var keyword = 'warrior';
var fifty_ch_before_keyword = str.split(keyword)[0].slice(-50);
var fifty_ch_after_keyword = str.split(keyword)[1].slice(0, 50);
```

Hope that helps!